# No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application, issue with Microsoft iOS Push Notification Tutorial

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have been through this tutorial found on Microsoft portal to send and receive iOS push Notification with Azure using Xamarin Forms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub

It is giving to me tons of headaches!

After several days spent in understanding why I am receiving this message

**No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application**

I still do not have an answer!

**Azure** is properly configured and the push notifications for Android work really well, but the ones for iOS have never worked!

Anyone else experiencing my same issue?

I have read many posts about the same issue, but no one is related to this tutorial.

*The only thing that is jumping on my mind is that  I am not the primary Apple Developer Account holder*, as suggested by Donald Ashworth into this post [Xamarin iOS RegisteredForRemoteNotifications intermittently not called Android works 100% of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275304/xamarin-ios-registeredforremotenotifications-intermittently-not-called-android-w)

I am testing the App on a physical iPAD with iOS 14.2

Comment: You need to  add `aps-environment` key in `entitilements.plist`  file with value as development or production .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT This is what I have in my Entitlements.plist but it does not work at all! I am using Token Authorization with P8 certificate on Azure and I switch between development and production string trying to understand where the problem is! I am struggling in solving this annoying issue: I would really appreciate your support. 

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <dict> <key>aps-environment</key> <string>development</string> </dict> </plist>'

Comment: I am facing the same issue